# Process template changes when upgrading to TFS 2013 from 2010 with Urban Turtle

Tags: tfs, tfs-process-template

we are about to upgrade to TFS 2013 from TFS 2010. And are having some problems with our process templates.

We are today using Urban Turtle with 2010 and we want to upgrade to the 2013 version of urban Turtle.

We have tried and gotten the process template to work in a clean 2013, but I am unable to find good information on what changes is needed to get the new "features" workitems and such to work in Urban Turtle 2013 and our custom Template.

My thought is maybe try downloading a clean 2010 process template/config for urban turtle and a clean for 2013 and then try compare the files for changes and then try to apply them manually to my custom template.

Is that the way to go or is there a good guide or so on what changes to make to the process template to get it to work?

**Edit:**
Thanks for the tips! Pasting all workitem changes is a lot (custom workflows, custom workitems, ..) so I rather not do that.
My main problem is as said the Urban Turtle part. They have this new "feature" workitem but we have an epic work item that is very similar. I want Urban Turtle to handle our epics as their "feature". I understand that how to do that depends on how my epic implementation is.

But my goal with this post was to get an answer with some good guide or information other than manually comparing the XML of the versions. so the question is "Is there any guide or information on how to upgrade process template to the 2013 Urban Turtle?". I **don't** need a solution for my specific template just some information.

Comment: maybe you should include an example of a new item and what you tried to get it to work.

Comment: Probably meaning the Feedback Request/Response and the Code Review Request/Response work items. And if you're upgrading from Scrum 1.0 to Scrum 2013 process templates, then you'll also want to remove the Sprint workitem etc. When doing an in place upgrade Visual Studio will probably still detect the old process template as being Visual Studio Scrum 1.0 in which case you can just tell it to use Visual Studio Scrum 2013 as a basis to apply the new features.

Comment: The upgrade guidance you're looking for can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194972.aspx

Comment: Thanks! Added some infrmation and reply as edit in the main post but the main thing is Urban Turtle process template changes.